# Is it possible to just grant users access to documents that are named after their uid in firestore using security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My question is how can i make this work.

```
rules_version: "2";
service cloud.firestore { //define used service
  match /databases/{databases}/documents { //not a specific database (important)
    match /{document == request.auth.token.sub} { //how can this work?
      //some more conditions and allows
    }
  }
}
```

Users should be able to access a number of databases but all the documents are named after the users UID, which is request.auth.token.sub, or so i think. The UID and the documents name should match. How can I write this in firebase-security-rules-language?

**Edit**

Here is my *working* solution:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /{database}/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && 
      request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, but you're using the wrong field and wrong test.  From firestore's documentation, you'd want it more like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Comment: As far as i understood the documentation the match blocks can be written as one that would say `match/databases/{database}/documents/{userId`. 
So i tried it with the two conditions but still got a permission denied error.

Comment: I think you're missing the point - a Firestore instance is linked to a *specific* database - there are ways to handle multiple databases with multiple instances, but you have to teach yourself that from the documentation.

BUT - possibly you are confusing "collections" for "databases"?  The "/databases/{database}/documents" refers to the top-level of your firestore instance, not to any of your *collections*; it is *below* this level that you have your collections and documents - and all documents *must* be in a collection/sub-collection. (editted to reflect that)

Comment: Ok after reading a lot more of that documentation I get your points and have it figured out. Your last comment was the decisive information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Firebase documentation on [content-owner access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#cloud-firestore_2), which contains this example for Firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /some_collection/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}
```